# Can I see the current health of my pets?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing a Witch Doctor, and I recently unlocked an ability which summons some pets, who appear to die only when they take an amount of damage.

How can I see how much health they have left?  If I'm about to enter a new area or face a boss, I'd prefer to have my pets at full strength, which might mean I need to re-summon them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that pets show up in the upper left hand corner of the screen:

[image]

In this area, you can find the current quantity and health of your currently summoned pets.